# Redis Sentinel -- Remote Monitoring

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel

I am trying to setup a Redis clustered environment. The setup is as follows (see pic via link):

- Replication: 1 Master, 1 Slave
- Failover: 3 Sentinels

[Deployment Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXPJs.png)

The issue that I am having is getting S3 to make the remote connection. In fact, I have tried simply deploying 1 Master and attempting the Sentinel remote connection but this too fails. Please see the simplified config files for the master and sentinel.
**local**
redis-server /path/to/local/redis.conf
*local/redis.conf*
`bind 127.0.0.1 192.168.20.37
 port 6379
 dir .`
**remote**
redis-sentinel /path/to/remote/sentinel.conf
*remote/sentinel.conf*
`bind 127.0.0.1 192.168.20.140
 port 16379
 sentinel monitor redis-cluster 192.168.20.37 6379 2`


After starting Sentinel on the remote image, Sentinel fails to connect to the master. See the following output:
`# oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo`
`# Redis version=4.0.8, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=15095, just started`
`# Configuration loaded`
`* Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was originally set to 1024).`
`* Running mode=sentinel, port=16379.`
`# Sentinel ID is 66c95f52fbc72b6a33009c36d9ac6b4e91988b81`
`# +monitor master mymaster 192.168.20.37 6379 quorum 2`
`# +sdown master mymaster 192.168.20.37 6379`
If I run Sentinel from the local image, making IP changes, it works as expected. No firewalls, no NAT. I should also note that I can successfully make remote client connections to the Master.
Any suggestions for this seemingly 'simple' setup?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by binding Sentinel to 0.0.0.0. It appears as though when you specify localhost + IP it only binds to localhost.